# How can i get only one solution from filter map?

Tags: scheme

```
(filter-map (lambda (x y) (and (eq? x z)   y) ) list1 list2 )
```

in scheme, i have two list `list1` and `list2`, if any element of `list1` equal to z, i want to return corresponding to `list2` element. i know only one element on `list1` equal to z.

My code is working but i get a result such that `'(bla)` but i want to only a result such that `bla` how can i remove this parentheses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `car` to retrieve the first element in the output list, but I don't think `filter-map` is the best option here - after all you're not interested in the list of results returned by `filter-map`, only in a single element - and this is unavoidable, a list *will* be returned even if it's empty. Basically, you need to look for a value in an association list. Try this instead:

```
(cdr (assq 'z (map cons list1 list2)))
=> 'bla
```

Explanation:

- `(map cons list1 list2)` builds an association list, where the elements in `list1` are the keys and the elements in `list2` are the values
- `assq` looks for the key-value pair that has `'z` as its key (using `eq?` for the comparisons), and returns that pair
- `cdr` returns the value part of that pair

Alternatively, you can check if your interpreter has a hash table implementation available (useful if you have to efficiently perform more than one search), for instance in Racket:

```
(hash-ref (make-hasheq (map cons list1 list2)) 'z)
=> 'bla
```

Explanation:

- `(map cons list1 list2)` builds an association list, where the elements in `list1` are the keys and the elements in `list2` are the values
- `make-hasheq` creates a new hash table using the association list, and uses `eq?` when finding a value given the key
- `hash-ref` returns the value corresponding to the key `'z`

Be aware that both of the above options will raise an error when we attempt to obtain the value if the key wasn't present in `list1`, you have to decide how to handle this case if the need arises; for example we can return `#f`:

```
(let ((pair (assq 'z (map cons list1 list2))))
  (and pair (cdr pair)))

(hash-ref (make-hasheq (map cons list1 list2)) 'z
          (const #f))
```

Comment: `assoc` doesn't raise an error if the key isn't found, it returns `#f`. Also, for `hash-ref`, you can pass in a procedure that is called if the key isn't found; it's just that the default procedure raises an error.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I didn't make myself clear, I meant that both `cdr` and `hash-ref` will rise an error when trying to obtain the _value_. I rephrased that part above, and added your suggestion ;)

Comment: `(and pair (cdr pair))`, or else use `(cond ((assoc ...) => cdr) ...)`. :-D

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Got it. Elegance, above all!

Comment: Great! Also, since the OP is using `eq?`, you can feasibly use `assq` and `make-hasheq` (assuming Racket's hash interface).

Answer (score 0):

The naive approach would be to call `car` on the result, since `car` returns the first element of a list. But that would cause an error if no element matches - your function would return an empty list, and `car` will fail.

Some languages (i.e. Haskell) implement an [option type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type). An option type is either empty or contains exactly one value. It's somewhat analogue to a list that can contains no more than one value. You can implement one for scheme and use it as the return type.

An alternative approach is to return the lists' first element, or `#f` (false) if no result was found. This approach is based on the fact that `Scheme` is a dynamic language.

Answer (score 0):

While `filter-map` is nice and functional, an iterative answer might be the more straightforward (read: intelligible) way to approach this.

```
#lang racket
(define list1 '(a b z d))
(define list1a '(a b c d)) ; doesn't have 'z in it
(define list2 '(1 2 3 4))
(define (find-matching-pair lst1 lst2)
  (let loop ((l1 lst1)
             (l2 lst2))
    (cond ((null? l1) #f) ; didn't find it
          ((eqv? (car l1) 'z) (car l2)) ; this ASSUMES l2 is not shorter than l1
          (else (loop (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
(find-matching-pair list1 list2) ; => 3
(find-matching-pair list1a list2) ; => #f
```